# Is it possible to scroll navigation bar to current file in VisualStudio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, IntelliJ Idea provides such feature: you can scroll navigation bar to the file you're currently working on. It's useful feature, especially when you're jumping around code and suddenly realised that you are lost in the project :)

Does VS code provide such a feature? Unfortunately, I could not find anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not natively supported in VS code. This sounds like something for UserVoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code if you would like to see this in VS Code.

Another option would be an extension that does this; however, I didn't see any way to actually highlight files in the workspace using the extension API at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api